# How do I filter a vector according to array in Statistics::Basic::ComputedVector?

Tags: perl, vector, filter, statistics, grep

I want to use a [Statistics::Basic::ComputedVector](http://p3rl.org/Statistics%3a%3aBasic%3a%3aComputedVector) `set_filter`, but the filter I want to use is an array of 1's and 0's. Is this possible?

Here's what I want to do:

```
my $v1 = vector(1,2,3,4,5);
my @filter = qw(1 0 0 1 1);
my $cv = computed($v1);
$cv->set_filter(@filter);
```

I tried the following:

```
my $v1  = vector(1,2,3,4,5);
my $compV1 = computed($v1);
my @filter = (1) x $compV1->query_size();
$filter[-1] = 0;
say $compV1;
$compV1-> set_filter( sub { grep { $filter[$_] } 0..$#_ } );
say $compV1;
```

… but this prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

What should I do?

It seems that this is a problem with my knowledge of `grep` and `map` more than `Statistics::Basic`, so I'd guess you could help even if you've never used this module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this filter:

```
$compV1->set_filter(sub { map { $filter[$_] ? $_[$_] : () } 0..$#_ });
```

Your second try is close, but you are returning indexes instead of real values.

Comment: This won't print an array of 0s and 1s ... why not just `$compV1->set_filter(sub { map { $filter[$_] } @_ });` ?  Or perhaps `$compV1->set_filter(sub { map { $filter[$_] + 0 } @_ });`

Comment: @reinierpost - my understanding of OP was that filter should pick those values `$v1` where `@filter` is set to 1. I might pick it up wrong.

Comment: That's not what it said, but always give the OP more than s/he asked for :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
->set_filter( sub { @_[ grep $filter[$_], 0..$#_ ] } )
```